# do the parantheses matter?

Tags: javascript, performance, increment, decrement

Given this [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/bit-increment) test

Why is this faster

```
var x;var i = 1E4;var j = 1E4;
for (; i-- > -1;) {
  x = -~x;
}
for (; j-- > -1;) {
  x = ~ - x;
}
```

Than this ?

```
var x;var i = 1E4;var j = 1E4;
for (; j-- > -1;) {
  x = -1 * ~x;
}
for (; j-- > -1;) {
  x = ~ (-1 * x);
}
```

Is the second version better optimizable, or what is the reason?

Comment: Are you resetting `j` somewhere in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second code sample, you use j as the iterator in both loops.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the second test you are either forgetting to reset `j` to `1E4`, or you meant to use an `i` in one of the loops. See this test:

http://jsperf.com/bit-increment/2

I added a snippet using `i` in the first loop and `j` in the second and it performs just as fast as the first test.

Comment: Thanks! :)  Dang how could I miss that :P

Comment: I'll accept his answer as it is his first answer and only a little bit later